# Backreferencing in bash

Tags: shell

I'm trying to devise an "elegant" solution to doing the following:

```
unzip applications/<abc>.zip -d applications/<abc>/
unzip applications/<def>.zip -d applications/<def>/
unzip applications/<ghi>.zip -d applications/<ghi>/
unzip applications/<jkl>.zip -d applications/<jkl>/
```

Brace expansions aren't applicable, they do the "reverse" of what I'm looking for (or am I missing something?).

Is a `for`-loop the way to go?
I had thought of using `xargs` or even exploiting history control (to backreference the argument with `!:1` or something); but things quickly get more complicated instead of simpler.

I think I'm biased by regex-backreferencing; does something like that exist in the shell?

Comment: Is there a pattern to the abc/de/ghi that could be generated?

Comment: If you're looking for sth more complicated than `for f in *.zip; do unzip -d "${f%.zip}" "$f"; done` then please add more info to your question. It's not at all obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A for loop, with some variable expansion rules may do what you want

```
for file in applications/*.zip
do
  unzip "$file" -d "${file%.zip}"
done
```

The expression `${file%.zip}` means "the contents of `$file` with with `.zip` removed from the end".

So first time round the loop `$file` may read `applications/abc.zip` and so `${file%.zip}` will read `applications/abc`.

Comment: You may need to append a `/` to unzip into the desired directory.

Comment: @RudiC That may depend on the version of `unzip`; on CentOS 7 it'll create the directory as necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned `xargs`. The xargs command appeared back in PWB/Unix, when neither the Thompson nor Mashey shell supported `for` loops. I think a `for` loop works best in your case. But it's kind of elegant to have programs make use of pipelines when possible, so here's how to do it with xargs:

```
printf "%s\n" abc def ghi jkl | xargs -I {} unzip applications/{}.zip -d applications/{}/
```

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is a variable; you just have to assign it in a previous/separate command:

```
a=abc
unzip applications/"$a".zip -d applications/"$a"/
a=def
!unzip
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a `for` loop is a good solution to your task.

```
for i in abc def ghi jkl; do
    unzip applications/"$i".zip -d applications/"$i"/
done
```

Or the same command on a single line,for use from the command line instead of a script:

```
for i in abc def ghi jkl; do unzip applications/"$i".zip -d applications/"$i"/; done
```

The quotes around`$i` are not necessary for the values from your example, but it's better to use quotes if you aren't sure that you will never have values with spaces or other special characters.